# How to read string variable in Jenkins pipeline script under post block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to read string variable in Jenkins pipeline script under post block

We created a Jenkins job to run our automation scripts. I am able to read the string parameter in Jenkins pipeline script but I am not able to read in pipeline script post block.

**String parameter.**
[image]

Pipeline script - Post blog.

[image]

How to replace the highlighted value with string parameter in post block.

I am able to read the parameter using the %projectName% in the pipeline script. But the same is not working in post block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `params.projectName` inside `${}` in double quoted string:

```
cucumber fileIncludePattern: '0.json', jsonReportDirectory: "C:/testing/newproject/domain/${params.projectName}/target"
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept helpful answers for your questions, this and previous.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its not working I given as "${params.projectName}"   ......

Comment: Console Output : [CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 5.0.1
[CucumberReport] JSON report directory is "C:/testing/newproject/domain/${params.projectName}/target"